# heroku not updateing

Tags: heroku

I'm using Heroku to deploy my rails app. But when I commit to git and push to Heroku, some things don't update from my local app

trouble shot common things
updated git locally 
checked status
pushed to heroku
heroku starts with no errors 
changes have not propagated to heroku ?

get this! text or html changed propagate

I've added a jquery script and it does not does not show up in the source when i view it?

The script works fine locally in dev and prod and the jquery shows up in the source?

I gust can't get it to heroku ?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are on `branch master` I just ran into a similar problem.  I made some commits.  Checked them out locally and they worked fine, but they weren't showing up on heroku. I even tried `heroku destroy` and `heroku create` Then I realized I was on my working/development branch. Once I did `git checkout master` and `git merge development-branch` followed by `git push heroku master`, the changes showed up on heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your commits are correct.  When you deploy, Heroku uses an entirely new slug to run your app from (which is a compiled version of your latest commit), so the idea of some stuff changing, and not others isn't possible.

Either your commits aren't correct, or you have some sort of caching issue getting in the way.

Comment: Thank-you Neil after some head scratching it became appearant that the code was dynamitacally being generated and those conditions were not being met on the new deploy. DOOOOOOO!!!